# How to deserialise a named XML node and grab all of its children C#

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I've the following XML which I can deserialise in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <MyDesc><![CDATA[DOCTOR WHO - PLANET OF THE DEA]]></MyDesc>
        <ActualStock><![CDATA[5]]></ActualStock>
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

However, if I add a new node eg MetaData, I do not know how to grab that node and all of its children as text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <MyDesc><![CDATA[DOCTOR WHO - PLANET OF THE DEA]]></MyDesc>
        <ActualStock><![CDATA[5]]></ActualStock>
        **<MetaData>
            <Desc>MD-Description - This is my product desc</Desc>
            <Image>MD - The main image</Image>
        </MetaData>**   
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

ie I want to grab and store everything within MetaData as one string.  The trouble is the children of MetaData are unknown.

Is this possible?

I thought the deserialiser would use this to match the MetaData node:

```
    [XmlElement("MetaData")]
    public List<MetaData> MetaDataList
    {
        get 
        {
            return metaDataList;
        }
        set
        {
            metaDataList = value;
        }
    }
```

and then figure out MetaData's children using:

```
    private List<MetaData> metaDataList = new List<MetaData>();

    public class MetaData
    {
        [XmlAnyElement]
        public List<string> Children
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm completely stuck...

Pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Sai.

Comment: Please see this question / answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921577/complex-xml-deserialization/24996406#24996406

Comment: well - I didnt realize i didnt get the "correct" answer on the question mentioned in my prior comment.  anyway - check my response on using xsd.exe

Comment: thank you  @GlennFerrie for responding quickly.  alas, the ability to generate code/class that deals with my xml isn't what I'm asking for help on.   the structure or the children of (in my example) MetaData are unknown.  it could be anything.    I just want to grab <MetaData>...</MetaData> and anything in between and simple store that fragment for future processing.   Looks like I might have to load the xml into an xmldocument and process it separately but I thought, hey can the xml deserialiser do this??  Thanks anyway.  Sai

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247370/value-field-of-deserialize-xml-has-no-value-when-using-xmlanyattribute

Comment: I would use XmlTextReader or dynamic to store those XML Snippets.  can you provide a few different varieties of what 'Metadata' might consist of so we can work up a working sample?

Comment: Hi @GlennFerrie,  I had to come up with an alternative solution which was based loosely on the link I posted above (ie had the children as attributes of a named node - <RUK title="..." price=".." description='...' /> etc.  The problem was that I was hoping that the deserialise method might do the trick automatically, and that I was missing something.  Anyway, project pressures meant I had to look for alternatives.  Marked Up your answer as being helpful too.  Sai.